# Best practices to configure multiple websites managed by multiple users on Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I am setting up a RedHat server with an Apache service to host multiple Wordpress websites.
We work with a few different companies which develop those websites.

I'm having trouble with the access rights management.
At this point, I started doing something like this :
/var/www/company1/website1

/var/www/company1/website2

/var/www/company2/website1

/var/www/company2/website2

And I created users company1 and company2.

Ideally, I want company1 to only be able to edit the subfolder in 'company1', and same thing for company2.
But I also need the apache user to have wxr rights on every folder.

I tried to setup chown as in 'company1:apache' for the folders in /var/www/company1, and 'company2:apache' for the folders in /var/www/company2, but by doing that company1 can also access company2 folders, and vice versa.

Would a chown as in 'apache:company1' et 'apache:company2' solve this issue and is it the best way to handle this ?

Users have a SSH access to the web server and should be able to copy their files in /var/www/companyX.

Comment: did you already jailed and chroot'ed the users into there directorys?

Comment: @djdomi No I didn't, I just created the users and haven't communicated them yet. At this point, their home directory is still the /home/companyX

Comment: if you set directory permissions for each company with 750 permission and company1:apache ownserhsip, and each company user does not belong to group apache they should not be able to access each others data.